# Does $\text{Aut}(E)\cong E$ hołd for elliptic curves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve over a field $K$.
Let $Aut(E)$ be a group of all automorphism of $E$ as algebraic curves.
Then, does $AutE\cong E$ holds ?

There is a natural injection $E\to \text{Aut}(E)$ given by $P\mapsto \{E\to E, Q\mapsto Q+P\}$.

To prove this is surjective, we should prove every automorpshims of $E$ is given by translation.

Background question:

Let $\text{Aut}(E,+)$ be an set of all isomorphism which commutes with $E$ action to $E$ itself (as trivial torsor).

Then, it is known that $\text{Aut}(E,+)\cong E$

(cf. lem$1.3$ of  https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0606580).

But I wonder why condition of 'commute with action' needed to prove this isomorphism, so I asked this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The isomorphism $AutE\cong E$ is never true. First of all, any elliptic curve also has an inversion map, sending $P$ to $-P$, which is not given by any translation. There also exist elliptic curves with complex multiplication, which have additional automorphisms besides these, though these are only finitely many (at most $24$ in characteristic $2$, $12$ in characteristic $3$ and at most $6$ otherwise). See Silverman, section III.10 for a discussion of these additional automorphisms.

Any automorphism of an elliptic curve fixing the origin is an isogeny, see Silverman section III.4. Therefore the automorphism group of $E$ as an algebraic curve will be the semidirect product of $E$ and the automorphisms of $E$ as an elliptic curve.

Comment: Thank you(+1). If you have additional thoughts on the isomorphism $Aut(E,+)\cong E$, I'm really appreciated.

Comment: I don't see the reason why any element of $Aut(E,+)$ is translation.

Comment: The fact that any element of $Aut(E,+)$ is a translation is exactly the statement of the lemma you cited (Lemma 1.3 in that paper). Do you have an issue with understanding the proof given there?

Comment: Yes, I don't have the reason why compatibility condition $f(P+Q)=f(P)+Q, \forall P,Q\in E(\overline{K})\times E(\overline{K})($ ensures that $f$ is translation. As you say, indeed $f : P\mapsto -P$ does not satisfy this condition.

Comment: A proof of this can be given as follows. Suppose that $f(P+Q)=f(P)+Q$ for all $P$ and $Q$, then we see that $f(P)=f(O+P)=f(O)+P$ for all $P$, where $O$ is the point at infinity. This implies that $f$ is translation by the element $f(O)$.

Comment: Oh God... The scales have fallen from my eyes. That's cool.